# How to get a custom field value of a custom post?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, pods-framework

What is the easiest way to get a custom field value from my custom post? I installed PODS plugin, created a new field and now I would like to get its value using PHP. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Had you looked at pods documentation? Sounds around [`pods_field_raw()`](http://staging.pods.io/docs/code/field-functions/pods-field-raw/).

Comment: Are you using PODS 2.0+? If so you are given the open to either use a custom database or the WP_meta standard. If you use the wp_meta then you can use the core WordPress functions to do this.